# Push Notification not working with Adhoc Profile

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com, ad-hoc-distribution

I have been trying this since last 2 days, but hard luck .I know this has been answered many times,and i went through all possible from them but none helped me .

So,I'm using UrbanAirship for receiving Push Notifications,however problem doesn't seems to be with UrbanAirship,because I am not even alerted for push notification when app launch 1st time .It worked very well for with Developer Certificates and Profiles but its not working when I try with Distribution certificates and Adhoc Profile.

I know its a very common error prone area between certificates and profiles,but apparently it does-not appear to be the problem with me. Here are the things I did :-

For the very first tine

1. Used the same app id(as used for development).
2. Enabled the push SSL for production environment,downloaded the same and installed.
3. Then from provisioning profile section I create new provisioning profile,deleted all older profiles from Xcode and installed new one .
4. Changed the scheme to release and created ipa,and installed it. But it never prompted for push notification on install .

   Afterwards I tried the same lot many times,with little changes like creating different app id and enabling push services only for production .
   Reading somewhere I also checked the  key value should be Production,which was also fine.

**Note**
I think this should not matter but I am using the same device for productions as used for development .

Comment: Abhinandan  did you changed gate way for it

Comment: You are not getting Push for AdHoc Distribution or for AppStore ?

Comment: Thanks Kamlesh,As I am using UrbanAirship,there is a option to select for distribution which apparently changes the gateway automatically if u select that option.However i dont think that is the problem becuase i am not asked for alert of push notification as well .

Comment: @Mtahir :- I am not getting it for Adhoc Distribution Profile.

Comment: How did you installed the app for AdHoc testing on your device ?

Comment: I created and ipa with release build using adhoc provisioning profile .You can check my 4th point

Comment: It is strange behavior, but as you are saying that it never prompted for push, have you tried to by checking the error from **didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError** in **AppDelegate** _ As you are AdHoc testing, you can store the value in some custom global object and display it in your first loaded view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44074/discussion-between-mtahir-and-abhinandan-sahgal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with UrbanAirship,nothing wrong with certificates or profiles ,    config.automaticSetupEnabled = NO; , i had to change this line to YES. 
I dont really understand how it was working with development build because UA doc says that if automaticSetupEnabled is set as no,you will have to mannualy resgister for Remote Notfications which I never did in my dev build,but it worked unlike release build.

Hope this will help someone our there in problem..!!
Thanks for the help.!!